# How to call addition operator on two objects?

Tags: java, object, polymorphism

In java, I have two `Object`s that addition (+) is supported on them, for example two `int`s or two `String`s. How I can write a function to really add them without specifying the types?

**note:** I don't want something like C++ function templates, as two operands are just `Object`s, i.e. I want to implement a function `add`:

```
Object add(Object a, Object b){
    // ?
}
```

and then be able to do something like this:

```
Object a = 1, b = 2;
Object c = add(a, b);
```

Comment: You write `add` for supported types.

Comment: `Object a = 1, b = 2;` without calling constructors?

Comment: what do you want the resulting object to be? What is the result of adding a string to a number?

Comment: @ryanm same behavior as java, e.g. `"s"+2` must be `"s2"`, however, `add` polymorphically returns it as `Object`.

Comment: Not doable without dirty custom hacks...but why would you want to do this?  Why not just keep track of the actual types of the object, and use the actual `+` operator?

Comment: In your 1, 2 example, should the result be 3 or "12"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too require something similar so I slapped together something which *hopefully* returns the same type as the built-in addition operator would return (except upcasted to Object). I used the [java spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf) to figure out the rules of type conversion, particular section 5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion. I haven't tested this yet:

```
public Object add(Object op1, Object op2){

    if( op1 instanceof String || op2 instanceof String){
        return String.valueOf(op1) + String.valueOf(op2);
    }

    if( !(op1 instanceof Number) || !(op2 instanceof Number) ){
        throw new Exception(“invalid operands for mathematical operator [+]”);
    }

    if(op1 instanceof Double || op2 instanceof Double){
        return ((Number)op1).doubleValue() + ((Number)op2).doubleValue();
    }

    if(op1 instanceof Float || op2 instanceof Float){
        return ((Number)op1).floatValue() + ((Number)op2).floatValue();
    }

    if(op1 instanceof Long || op2 instanceof Long){
        return ((Number)op1).longValue() + ((Number)op2).longValue();
    }

    return ((Number)op1).intValue() + ((Number)op2).intValue();
}
```

And in theory you can call this method with numerical reference types, numerical primitive types, and even Strings.

Answer (score 3):

if you just care that the parameters are "Object" types but can specify the types INSIDE the add() method you can use "instanceof"

```
private Object add(Object a, Object b) {
    // check if both are numbers
    if (a instanceof Number && b instanceof Number) {
        return ((Number) a).doubleValue() + ((Number) b).doubleValue();
    }

    // treat as a string ... no other java types support "+" anyway
    return a.toString() + b.toString();
}

public void testAdd()
{
    Object a = 1;
    Object b = 3;
    Object strC = "4";
    Object numResult = add(a, b);
    Object strResult = add(strC, a);
}
```

Comment: if a and b are `int`s, this implementation will return a `double` instead of a `int`.

Comment: yes but from your question, that is still valid since you only care that you return a working Object type.  There are many number types in java.  If you need it to be specific to int, you can change the checks/casts to type:Integer accordingly.